# TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routerlink

I got this TS2322 error, when i tried to build my angular app.

I have a [link]="i" where i eq index number.
When i declare it i use this: @Input() link!: string;

Link used by reference for routerLink
like this: [routerLink]="link"

if i change link!: number, then i got this error:
TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | any[] | null | undefined'.
for this part of the code:
<a [routerLink]="link">

in my opinion routerLink needs string?!?! but than why is it triggerd, when i used link as string?
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you declare it as string, the value should be string only.
In your case you can try passing i value as string  [link]="'i'"
or
You can make @Input() link: any;  to pass any type of value

Comment: Ahaaam i never thinked it will be work, but thanks for it